# Can we enforce that programs must be runnable in questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, flags, minimal-reproducible-example

Can we please enforce the "C" in MCVE? ("Complete" if you didn't know, I sure hope you did)

There are so many questions where the OP doesn't care enough to make a runnable example, so he/she gives an incomplete example with variables all over the place which we cannot understand. This makes questions very hard to answer, and only wastes our precious time.

Should we have a flag or something that says *"Incomplete code example - Please make a **complete, runnable** example which captures your problem"*, or is there already a flag which includes that?

Lastly, [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) both say that the program must be runnable, and should be on the "How to ask" pane(on the right when asking a question) in my opinion. This might prevent this problem, or at least help it.

Comment: What if the problem is that the code *doesn't run*? "Complete" doesn't mean "runnable".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

We already have a close-vote reason for that.

> Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary* to reproduce **it in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

If you do not yet have close-vote privileges, you can find that reason under flags.

Comment: That's true, I forgot about that flag, but I still think that making the code example runnable is very important, and should be better enforced.

Comment: @Tommy: closure is plenty of enforcement.  And not all technology is readily runnable (try re-training a neural network to the same inputs to reproduce an edgecase, for example).